# Application to Vizualize Task

Tags: windows, web-apps, data-visualization, planning

I am looking for an application (open source, freeware etc.) that has ability to visualize the task into a map with following title "To do", "Doing" and "Done". The map should be similar as the picture below.

I also want to add, remove and update task.

I want to use the application in my daily life.

[image]

Comment: What operating system? is a webapp OK? Do you need synchronization with other software? Non-free OK?

Comment: Iam using Windows 7. Webapp or software is acceptacble. Both sync and non-sync. Both free and non-free

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear whether you'd be happy with a web app, but assuming you would, I think that [Trello](http://www.trello.com) does what you are asking well - it allows you to create task boards that are grouped into lists. The default lists are named To do, Done and Doing, but these can be renamed.

If you ever need to extend the list to multiple people, like friends or family, there is good support for collaboration.

There are also apps available for all the usual mobile devices. I should add that it is free.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may also find [Eylean Board](http://www.eylean.com/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=DMStack) suitable. It provides the features you are looking for as well as many additional ones that could prove useful when working in a larger team.

[image]